# Unexpected non-void return value in tableview

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, parse-platform, swift3

I have a tableview controller and for the tableview I'm registering two cells. Depending on the data in the database will determine which cell will be registered for each row of the tableView. But there is a pointer in my class I use to fetch data from another class and I have to fetch the data first before I can determine which cell is used and the code I have is in a void function and I'm now having trouble returning the cell. Here is my code. I'm getting this error "Unexpected non-void return value in void function" when I try to return CellOne and cellTwo in the code below

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath, object: PFObject?) -> PFTableViewCell? {
    let CellOne = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cellone", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellOne
    let CellTwo = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CellTwo", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! CellTwo

    let CellObject = object?["Home"] as? PFObject
    CellObject?.fetchIfNeededInBackground(block: { (cellsObject, error) in
        if error == nil{
            if cellsObject?["CellType"] as? String == "land"{
                return CellOne
            }else{
                return CellTwo
            }
        }else{

        }
    })
}
```

Comment: `cellForRow(at:)` is too late to fetch the data. You need to have fetched the data previously so that you can quickly and simply return the correct cell. You are currently trying to return a cell from a closure. Apart from the fact that the closure is a void return, it also completes asynchronously

Answer (score 0):

Try to put your condition inside a function before loading your tableview, create a variable to get the value true or false, and inside your tableview just make sure it is true open the cellOne else cellTwo

Answer (score 0):

You are not returning anything from the function, you are returning a cell from within a close, but the function completes without returning anything.